# なんどもあります　OR　たくさんあります？

Tags: word-choice

If someone asks, てんぷらをたべたことがありますか？

I read that you can answer with なんどもあります. However, I thought it would be たくさんあります. They both mean, "I've done it many times." Right?

Comment: @Szymon, I don't think we're supposed to edit questions in quite that way... as you've wiped out at least 1 place where the asker could learn something.

Comment: @virmaior I changed "drink" to "eat" as the question is not about that. I also corrected a spelling mistake in たくさん. I didn't touch grammatically incorrect part of the question that needs to be corrected in an answer.

Comment: @Szymon - yes, you're right. one does not drink tempura. smh, at myself.

Comment: I'm not saying the asker would be opposed to your changes or that they are substantively wrong --  they are of course right. At the same time, I don't think　たくさんなあります is a spelling mistake. It's a grammar mistake of misusing a 形容動詞.

Comment: @virmaior it was たくさな, not たくさんな.

Comment: @virmaior - it was a spelling mistake. it was supposed to be たくさんあります. but now i'm interested in knowing how たくさんなあります is a grammar mistake though.

Comment: 「なんどあります」は、きっと「[何度]{なんど}*も*あります」ですよね。

Comment: @Chocolate さん、ごめんなさい。ども、ありがとうございます。

Comment: Out of curiosity, is my question not answerable? Or something?

Comment: "ども、ありがとうございます。" << ダジャレですか?

Comment: なんどもあります is only for countable events, but たくさんあります can be applied for uncountables (e.g. liquid volume) also.

Comment: @Earthliŋ - 「ダジャレ」はなんですか?

Comment: ダジャレは・・・ pun だと思います、たぶん。

Answer (score 4):

I think both is OK but なんどもあります sounds more common.

たくさん also goes more natural with small things happening a lot, like 転{ころ}ぶ、失敗{しっぱい}する.

For example:

> 何度{なんど}も失敗{しっぱい}しました <- "I failed many times"
>
> たくさん失敗{しっぱい}しました <- Same meaning but each failure sounds more numerous and less severe
>
> 何度{なんど}も成功{せいこう}しました <- "I succeeded many times"
>
> たくさん成功{せいこう}しました <- "I succeeded a lot of times", which sounds a bit strange